# How to store what is generated by the analyser?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, stop-words

Let's say that I use this mapping:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1, 
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "testtype": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "english",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can index a document:

```
PUT test/testtype/0
{
   "content": "The Quick Brown Box"
}
```

And I can retrieve it:

```
GET test/testtype/0
```

Which will return me:

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "testtype",
  "_id": "0",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "content": "The Quick brown Fox"
  }
}
```

I know that in the source field you are supposed to only have the document that you inserted this is why I specified in my mapping that I want to store my content field. So by querying my store field I would expect to have in it what is generated my the analyser so something like this:

```
"quick brown fox"
```

But when I query the stored field:

```
GET test/testtype/_search
{
  "stored_fields": "content" 
}
```

I have exactly what I wrote in my document:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "testtype",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "content": [
            "The Quick brown Fox"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So my question is how can I store in my elasticsearch the result of what is generated by my analyser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is about the difference between the stored text and the generated tokens:
[the store attribute of a lucene field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181168/the-store-attribute-of-a-lucene-field)

A stored field contains exactly the same as the corresponding field in the "_source"-JSON.

The generated token are in a lucene internal representation. But you can use the [`_analyze`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) or [`_termvectors`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) endpoint to have see the token
or you can use the [term-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set index or query time analyzer. If you are using index time analyzer, then the analyzed text will be stored.

More details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html

Another way is using multifields. That means you have the original, and the processed text as well.

More details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: I read the link you provide but for me it's just store the same things but analysed through different methodology and I cannot access to what the analyser has produced. Could you provide an example?

Comment: "By default, field values are indexed to make them searchable, but they are not stored. This means that the field can be queried, but the original field value cannot be retrieved."

This from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html

Check out this link too, and after that i can provide a sample for you if needed. Set 'store' to true.

Comment: I already have set in my mapping that store should be true but it doesn't seem to work